# Delete line after keyword1 if keyword2 does not exist

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, grep

How do I delete lines after "/test1/end" that does not contain test1

**test_long_sentence.txt:**

```
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
20  /test1/end=category
**This is some unwanted data blah blah blah**
20  /test1/Purpose=
20  /test1/my_purpose="To create 
a fun-filled moment"
20  /test1/end=Purpose
...
```

**Expected Output:**

```
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
20  /test1/end=category
20  /test1/Purpose=
20  /test1/my_purpose="To create 
a fun-filled moment"
20  /test1/end=Purpose
...
```

I tried :

```
grep -A1 'end' test_long_sentence.txt| sed 'test1/!d' test_long_sentence.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '/test1/{f=0} !f{print}  /test1\/end/{f=1}' sentence.txt  
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
20  /test1/end=category
20  /test1/Purpose=
20  /test1/my_purpose="To create 
a fun-filled moment"
20  /test1/end=Purpose
```

#### How it works

When awk starts, any undefined variable is, by default, false.  So, when awk starts `f` will be false.  Awk will then read each line in turn and perform the following three commands:

- `/test1/{f=0}`

  For any line containing `test1`, we set variable `f` to false (0).

  When we are in a range of lines that we want to print `f` will be set to false.
- `!f{print}`

  If `f` is false, print the current line.
- `/test1\/end/{f=1}`

  For any line that contains `test1/end`, set `f` to true (1).

  This signals that we should not print the lines that follow until we reach a line that contains `test1`.

#### Using variables

```
awk -v a="test1" -v b="test1/end"  '$0~a{f=0} !f{print}  $0~b{f=1}' sentence.txt
```

Comment: what if there is an **unwanted data** between Faries" and 20  /test1/type="Western".  I will have to check for end of line that ends with quote and check next line whether it consist of test1?